# simple_shell project , _getline() is returning something wrong

Tags: shell

The problem is in the file line.c in the function int _getline(info_t *in,char **b, size_t *a)

Apparently it's return[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV13r.png)  is not correct, but there are 3 return calls made,so I'm looking into which it goes(but it's supposed to go to the last return call return(getting);
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSnIg.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also read the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash).  Also https://shellcheck.net is the first place to figure out syntax problems. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or other) as your first line of scripting.